# Why Indentation Required in .yaml file in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I just coding in flutter and i show that when I set assets and only one spacing or indentation mitch match in .yaml file  it gives error

`Expected a key while parsing a block mapping.`

I just want to know why indentation is required in .yaml file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because that's how the yaml language is defined. Indentation denotes structure.

Comment: #tip for getting spacing right in .yaml files: instead of blank spaces, use a character like % (easy to count). When you're done typing code, replace (Edit > Find > Replace) % with one blank space